# How to scale along the X-axis values and range options using the nvd3 charts?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nvd3.js, daterangepicker

I'm using NVD3 charts for generating graphs. I wanted to change and customize the values and date range value along the X-axis.

Currently the graph uses the default values generated by the graph, but i want to able to customize the X-axis values.

I'm looking at the bootstrap nvd3 example: http://www.dangrossman.info/2012/08/20/a-date-range-picker-for-twitter-bootstrap/
however from the example ( as shown for the case of 'Last 30 days').

I'm not quite sure, how and where can I change the x-labels, so as to make them consecutive instead of alternative?

Eg: in the example for the case 'Last 30 days', shows on the x-axis:

[image]

how can i customize the graph to become :

June24  June 25    June 26   June 27   ---- along the x-axis?
any ideas how to achieve?

Thanks!

EDIT::::::::

Here is the fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/dxkmtg5j/2/

```
chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
                        return d3.time.format.utc(dataFormat)(new Date(d));
                });
```

Following is the o/p that i get labeled on the 'x' axis

[image]

Sorry that is the only code i could present since I dont have much clue where to start with handling the labels for the x axis. I changed the 'dateRangePciker.js' file and thats where i tried to modify some code. This might not be sufficient, but if i could get a high level idea for the implementation, i can try form my side.

Thanks

Comment: Can you put the code you have worked on so far on a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: And the example link you have provided is one of `highcharts` not `NVD3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this code and create a date

```
chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {            
        var dx = testdata[0].values[d] && testdata[0].values[d].x || 0;
        if (dx > 0) {
            console.log(dx);
            return d3.time.format('%X')(new Date(dx))
        }
         return null;
    }).axisLabel("direction").showMaxMin(false);
```

Comment: thanks, the tickFormat() could work, but I was trying to add the data dynamically into the axisLabel(), instead a text? Is it possible? something like: axisLabel(dx)??

Comment: Read this [blogpost](http://channagayan.blogspot.in/2014/08/adding-string-values-to-nvd3-line-chart.html)  for more details.